# Proc import imports wrong datatype from CSV

Tags: csv, import, sas

I have been trying to import CSV into a process node which doesnt care about rest of the fields (dynamic in count of fields as well) but for 2 or 3. But in those other fields I have date fields that is being imported  in a wrong way. The field gets automatically assigned as Date20. while it is actually datetime. Also another field that is supposed to be a 16 digit character is being imported as number and is getting truncated (shows in the form 9.401153E15). After processing, this node exports the data into CSV and I see all these errors there.

I checked few links like http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/038-30.pdf which is relevent to the topic but irrelevent in the context. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

`PROC IMPORT` for CSV simply generates datastep code, so I would recommend simply copying the datastep code into your program (it should be visible in the log) and editing it to reflect your needs.

Comment: and if you don't like copy and paste and you are in the old IDE, you can get it by Run->Recall Last Submit.  That will paste it to the top of your active code editor.

Comment: The problem here is that I am of no liberty to assume what all fields shall come in the CSV. The CSV could have n number of fields. And this particular case comes only in certain situations.

Comment: If that's the case, and you need to do this programatically (ie, not manually), you will likely need to address this through some sort of data dictionary where you generate the input statement from the metadata (data dictionary).  It is possible you could also convert the date to datetime fields on the fly, depending on the data, but that becomes more complicated and risks potential issues.

Comment: Alright. Thanks Joe. Let me do some research in this direction.